# Join tables but keep matches in a single row

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables structure in a **PostgreSQL** DB:

[image: Tables structure]
These tables have this content:

[image: Tables data]

So if I want to retrieve the SB associated to each server I'll need to join these 3 tables:

- Server with Map_ServerSB on server.Id = Map_ServerSB.IdObj1
- Map_ServerSB with SB on Map_ServerSB.IdObj1 = SB.Id

The thing is that, this way, I'll get 2 records.

However, I would need to get a single record; something like this:

[image: Actual and expected results]

Note: We won't have more than 2 records in SB for each server (there could be zero, one or two records for each server)

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: What should the output be if there is one SB for a server?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: It could be something like: ServerId SB1 SB2 and there would be data under ServerId and SB1 only (NULL under SB2). Sorry but it's difficult to explain without a table. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and comments is not the best place to write or read code. That's why we always suggest to put code and table structure (CREATE TABLE) in the question and **in text**. Even better if you write your code in a site like [dbfiddle.uk](dbfiddle.uk), so others can reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll keep it in mind for upcoming posts.

Answer (score 0):

You need either 2 more joins, or to do a `GROUP BY` first (to collapse the two rows into one) and then join `Map_ServerSB` and `SB` (twice). In a query:

```
SELECT
    s.Id     AS ServerId,
    s.Name   AS Server_Name,
    sb1.Name AS SB_1,
    sb2.Name AS SB_2
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
           ms.IdObj1,
           MIN(ms.IdObj2)
               AS sb_id_1,
           CASE WHEN MIN(ms.IdObj2) <> MAX(ms.IdObj1)
               THEN MAX(ms.IdObj1) ELSE NULL
           END
               AS sb_id_2
        FROM 
            Map_ServerSB AS ms
        GROUP BY
            ms.IdObj1
    ) AS ms
    JOIN Server AS s
      ON s.Id = ms.IdObj1
    JOIN SB AS sb1 
      ON ms.sb_id_1 = sb1.Id
    LEFT JOIN SB AS sb2 
      ON  ms.sb_id_2 = sb2.Id
  ;
```